# Check Permissions for Each Logged-In Subject

Tags: shiro

In our application, we store WebSocket information within an authenticated User's session.  When new data arrives, we'd like to broadcast it to all active users who have permission to see the particular data set. How do I get the Subject for all active sessions?  (With the Subject, I can then checkPermission() prior to delivering the data set.)

I know how to get all the active sessions.  I know how to set the DefaultSessionStorageEvaluator to save the PrincipalCollection in the session.  I know that RememberMeManager sees the Subject.  I know about AuthenticationListener.  I know about sub-classing various classes to override various login and authenticated methods.

Do I need to maintain my own map from PrincipalCollection -> Subject?  Have I overlooked one in the existing code base?  Should I store the Subject itself in the Session?

Answer (score 0):

You get the Subject for an active Session by building a new Subject for each Session (no need to keep one around).  As such:

```
...getActiveSessions()
  .forEach (session -> 
     new Subject.Builder()
       .session (session)
       .buildSubject()
       .execute (() -> /* consume w/ Subject 'bound' */));
```